# Can't Install corefonts from Winetricks

Tags: 16.04, winetricks

I installed FL-Studio 12 in my Ubuntu 16.04 but the menu texts and all text related things didn't appeared. I googled it and found that I need to install `corefonts` from `Winetricks`. But when I tried to install it an error appeared saying

> sha1sum mismatch! Rename
>   /home/lenovo/.cache/winetricks/corefonts/arial32.exe and try again.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Did you try what it suggests and rename the arial32.exe file?

Comment: I can't find the /.cache/ file. And can I rename it through terminal?

Comment: You have to go to `cd ~/.cache/winetricks/corefonts/` and then rename it in terminal as `mv arial32.exe arial32.exe.orig` or something similar to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file `arial32.exe` needs to be renamed.

In terminal go to the `corefonts` folder and then rename the file:

```
cd ~/.cache/winetricks/corefonts/
mv arial32.exe arial32.exe.orig
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Recently I've met the same problem. To solve it I've switched to the latest version of `winetricks`. In short the steps are:

```
sudo apt purge winetricks

cd ~/Downloads
wget  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Winetricks/winetricks/master/src/winetricks
chmod +x winetricks 
sudo mv winetricks /usr/local/bin
```

Please note at this stage `winetricks` will be available only from the command line. More details can be found at: https://wiki.winehq.org/Winetricks

In addition I want to report that with the current [Staging branch](https://www.winehq.org/search?q=ubuntu) I'm able to play StarCraft II more fluently than in Windows :P

Comment: Thank you! I've tried everything possible and I forgot to check WineHQ page. It works like a charm now!